# SQL 2005: logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect checksum

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I got this error this morning during the execution of a SSIS package:
SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect checksum (expected: 0x5fb84eb5; actual: 0x7fb84eb5). It occurred during a read of page (1:6434165) in database ID 8 at offset 0x00000c45aea000 in file 'D:\Data\REPORTING.mdf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

I ran DBCC CHECKDB and it found no errors:
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'REPORTING'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

However, I do see an entry for that page_id in the suspect_pages table.

Do I have a problem or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, although the problem may be memory. I suggest you upgrade SQL Server 2005 to the latest release, and if that is check the CU upgrade level at SQLRELEASESERVICES (Type it into google - it ia blog by the team releasing monthly (!) updates). Maybe you also run into an issue on the sfotware side.